# Switching computers for 3D printer

Tags: marlin, diy-3d-printer, firmware

Does anyone know how to move a project I'm working on in VSCode on my Mac onto a different Windows computer? It's a Marlin firmware file using Auto Build Marlin and I want to move it from my main Mac computer to the old Windows computer I'm designating for the 3D printer.

Comment: Seems like this is more of a coding question than a 3d printing question ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use version control to keep the project on GitHub, then you can clone the project to anywhere you like:

- [How to add a new project to Github using VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877667/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-github-using-vs-code)
- [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

There's quite a lot of reading there, but you will end up with a more robust result than simply copying files across.